# DryIoc: Different Dependency from different Factory by Condition

Tags: dryioc

I tried something like this:

```
container.Register<IFactory, WebFactory>(
    serviceKey: "t");

container.Register<IConfigurationProvider>(made: Made.Of(
    r => ServiceInfo.Of<IFactory>(serviceKey: "t"), 
    f => f.Create()), setup: Setup.With(condition:
        req => req.Parent.Enumerate().Any(p => 
            p.ServiceType.Namespace.StartsWith("Namespace"))));


container.Register<IFactory, OtherFactory>(
    serviceKey: "c");

container.Register<IConfigurationProvider>(made: Made.Of(
    r => ServiceInfo.Of<IFactory>(serviceKey: "c"), 
    f => f.Create()), setup: Setup.With(condition:
        req => req.Parent.Enumerate().Any(p => 
            p.ServiceType.Namespace.StartsWith("OtherNamespace"))));


container.Register<IFactory, DefaultFactory>();
container.Register<IConfigurationProvider>(made: Made.Of(
    r => ServiceInfo.Of<IFactory>(), f => f.Create()));         
container.Register<IConfigured, Configured>(made: Made.Of(() =>
    new Configured(Arg.Of<IConfigurationProvider>())));


namespace Namespace {
    class MyService {
        MyService(IConfigured configured) {
        }
    }
}


namespace OtherNamespace {
    class MyOtherService {
        MyOtherService(IConfigured configured) {
        }
    }
}
```

But DryIoc just injects the last registred one of IConfigurationProvider and ignores the condition. I simplyfied the Code massive and replaced the Names in the configuration (Yes, the Services-Classes are registred).

A better documentation of conditions and RequestInfo would be nice.

EDIT: I now assume, that the problem is my default registration of a factory and DryIoc just uses the last.

EDIT2: What exactly represents RequestInfo? The one who is Requested? So this means Configured? Or is RequestInfo.Parent Configured? What does Enumerate? The whole Dependency Tree?

Comment: From where do you use the container, from Asp.Net Core?

Comment: RequestInfo represents the info about the injected dependency at hand. The Parent is injecting/consuming service. Enumerate traverses all parents up from dependency to resolution root.

Comment: Yes from ASP.net Core with services.AddControllersAsServices(). What is the "injected dependency" in my example? Parent is the MyService or MyOtherService instance?

Comment: In respect to IConfigured dependency, tbe both are parents but on different request chains

Comment: This doesnt help. The configuration of both are near equal with the same class structure but with different names. If I call req.Parent what EXACTLY is Parent in my example? And what represents req? req == IConfigurationProvider and req.Parent == IConfigured and req.Parent.Parent == MyService / MyOtherService?

Comment: Okay, i found a way to debug and look in req. RequestInfo is the one who is requested e.g. IConfigurationProvider, req.Parent is the IConfigured implementation and req.Parent.Parent is one of the services.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160163/discussion-between-user2429841-and-dadhi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a bug in condition used together with instance factory. Need a time to find out.

The workaround for the moment (DryIoc 2.12.5) will be adding `asResolutionCall: true` to setups with conditions. Actually it should not be required, and DryIoc should do that automatically behind the scenes to prevent caching of first condition result. That why it is likely a bug.

Here is the [working sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ku4BD) from the [comments chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160163/discussion-between-user2429841-and-dadhi).

Regarding code in a question, the registrations with condition should be modified like this (reformatted a bit for readability):

```
container.Register<IConfigurationProvider>(
    made: Made.Of(r => ServiceInfo.Of<IFactory>(serviceKey: "t"), f => f.Create()), 
    setup: Setup.With(asResolutionCall: true,
        condition: r => r.Parent.Enumerate().Any(
             p => p.ServiceType.Namespace.StartsWith("Namespace"))));

container.Register<IConfigurationProvider>(
    made: Made.Of(r => ServiceInfo.Of<IFactory>(serviceKey: "c"), f => f.Create()), 
    setup: Setup.With(asResolutionCall: true,
        condition: r => r.Parent.Enumerate().Any(
             p => p.ServiceType.Namespace.StartsWith("OtherNamespace"))));
```

Comment: It seems, that the performance of asResoultionCall is rather bad, or it's my instance which is expensive. But if I set my IConfigurationProvider-Register-Statement on reuse: Reuse.Singleton, the registration seems to be never used, but the IDependOnDependency has a transient reuse.

Comment: Performance will be worse, yes as you may predict. I will look using the sample from the chat with Singleton.Reuse

Comment: I'm sorry, Reuse.Singleton works fine. Seems to be a misconfiguration by me. Thank ou for your great work.